# Why is this not a valid python DateTime insert in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I'm getting the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (exceptions.TypeError) SQLite DateTime
>   type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.

When trying to insert the following datetime instance in the `dvdrelease` column:

`'dvdrelease': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 3, 0, 53, 32, 682000)`

I'm using Arrow behind the scenes to do some string parsing, and arrow is returning the value in the code above (value = `datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 3, 0, 53, 32, 682000)`)

Example of arrow code: (the string received ALWAYS follows the following format: "Jan 3", "Dec 22", "Jun 3".)

```
#!venv/bin/python
import arrow
import time
import datetime

# arrow string parsing
def string_to_date(y):
    ''' Takes a MON d (Jan 3) string and converts it into a full date and time '''
    # get current times
    time_now = arrow.utcnow()
    this_year = str(time_now.year)
    this_hour = str(time_now.hour)
    this_minute = str(time_now.minute)
    this_second = str(time_now.second)
    this_milli = str(time_now.microsecond)

    time.sleep(0.1) # sleep so the microseconds variables never match

    full_time = y + " " + this_year + " " + this_hour + " " + this_minute + " " + this_second + " " + this_milli
    final_output = arrow.get(full_time, 'MMM D YYYY H m ss SSS').naive
    return final_output
```

But why does SQLite say this isn't a valid insert?

for what it's worth, here's how this Column is defined in my `models.py` file (a Flask web-app):

`dvdrelease = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)`

I've also done `type()` on my variables before insertion:

`Nov 3`
`<type 'unicode'>`
`2015-11-03 01:26:48.389000`
`<type 'datetime.datetime'>`

Comment: Did you read [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#date-and-time-types)? Also, are you sure that the dvdrelease column has that datetime value? Did you try using that example directly? Also, please show more code, ideally a self-contained example that shows the problem.

Comment: Yes I have read some of the documentation. I'm sure the dvdrelease column has that value because I'm not even inserting it manually. I don't understand what do you mean by using the example directly. I've added my string to datetime code. Not sure what else is needed.

Comment: (1) create a minimal but complete code example: I would try to pass `datetime(...)` directly to SQLite and see if it works -- if it doesn't then remove `string_to_date()` from the question. In any case, add the code that inserts the date. (2) unrelated: you don't need `arrow` here: `d = datetime.strptime(month_day_string, '%b %d')` `return datetime.utcnow().replace(month=d.month, day=d.day)` (you could add the current year, to take into account leap years)